# Am having problems with the MyCap app not taking photos

Tags: redcap

In my REDCap survey I want participants to upload a photo through the MyCap application

However in the MyCap Andriod app [v1.12.0-88] the question doesn't appear at all
and in the MyCap Apple app [v2.20.0] the question appears but provides an open text field

I've seen the photo option work on the UCD youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vy9908QLx04) but on my phone and two of my colleagues phones we're all having the above mentioned issues

Has anyone had the photo option work on their MyCap? If so, did it work automatically or did you do something to make it work? Do I need to ask for help/permission from my administrator?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I received a reply from the VUMC team and apparently you need to add

@MC-FIELD-FILE-IMAGECAPTURE

to the field annotation area